# org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught while copying

Tags: java

I'm trying to copy some files created in my server to FTP using code in below method. But weird thing is i'm getting below error randomly and i couldn't figure out what is happening.

```
Exception =org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught while copying.
```

Below is the code by which i'm copying the files to FTP.

```
public void copyDumpsToFTP() throws SocketException, IOException
  {



      FTPClient f= new FTPClient();
      f.connect(dumpProperties.getProperty("ftpIPAddress"));
      boolean flag =f.login(dumpProperties.getProperty("ftpUser"),dumpProperties.getProperty("ftpPassword"));
      System.out.println(" is connected to FTP ::"+flag);

      // setting fileType to binary

      boolean isFileTypeChanged =f.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);


      // System.out.println(" Is file type changed to binary :: "+isFileTypeChanged);
      // change working directory of FTP Server

      boolean isDirectoryChanged =f.changeWorkingDirectory(dumpProperties.getProperty("ftpDirectory"));

      System.out.println(" Is the FTP working directory Changed :: "+isDirectoryChanged);




      // to copy engineering dump from source to FTP

      InputStream inputFileEngg = new FileInputStream(new File(dumpNameEngineering));



      boolean isSavedEngg = f.storeFile(dumpProperties.getProperty("dumpNameOfEnggInFTP"), inputFileEngg);
      System.out.println("is Engineering dump File Saved in FTP Server :: "+isSavedEngg);
      System.out.println(" Engg Dump sucessfully Created and Saved in FTP...");


   // to copy correspondance dump from source to FTP

     InputStream inputFileCorr = new FileInputStream(new File(dumpNameCorrespondance));   

      boolean isSavedCorr = f.storeFile(dumpProperties.getProperty("dumpNameOfCorrInFTP"), inputFileCorr);
      System.out.println("is Correspondance File Saved in FTP Server :: "+isSavedCorr);
      System.out.println(" Correspondance Dump sucessfully Created and Saved in FTP...");

   // to copy tmg dump from source to FTP

       InputStream inputFileTmg = new FileInputStream(new File(dumpNameTmg));       

      boolean isSavedTmg = f.storeFile(dumpProperties.getProperty("dumpNameOfTmgInFTP"), inputFileTmg);
      System.out.println("is TMG File Saved in FTP Server :: "+isSavedTmg);
      System.out.println(" TMG Dump sucessfully Created and Saved in FTP...");




  }
```

The program is executing till SOP statement `Is the FTP working directory Changed :: true`

and latter it had thrown error as mentioned above.

Comment: Looks like some `catch` block is "helpfully" suppressing the full stack trace, which would include the root cause.  First thing you need to do is modify the code to print the complete stack trace and include it in your post (edit the post).

Comment: Or else you yourself have failed to provide the full stack trace, which alone contains the secret cause.

Comment: Same error for me when using Apache FTPClient.Could not found the solution

Answer (score 0):

The directory you are changing should exists on the same path and it should have proper write permission so that FTP can write on it.

here...

```
boolean isDirectoryChanged =f.changeWorkingDirectory(dumpProperties.getProperty("ftpDirectory"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when disk space is not available or disk quote exceed.

Comment: Or other things.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this problem, the disk space of the ftp server to be boarded was full.